# Is there a way to replace a component onPress in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In React-Native I am using this component `<SimpleLineIcons name='heart' size={32} style={{position: 'absolute', left: 10}}/>` I want so that when I click on it, it gets replaced with this component `<AntDesign name='heart' size={32} color="red" style={{position: 'absolute', left: 10}}/>`. How can I do this?

Comment: you can conditionally render those components, that will be based on some ```buttonPressed``` state.

Comment: Create a state say `const [isClicked, setClicked] = useState(false)` and then when the component is clicked, change it to true. And render the components conditionally, like `{isClicked ? (<Simple> : <Ant>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an item in the state, called `toggleIcon`. This will dictate what component to display. Then, to conditionally render the two component simply use a ternary operator like this:

```
export const MockComponent = () => {
  const [toggleIcon, setToggleIcon] = React.useState(false);
  
  return (
    <>
      // ...
      {toggleIcon ? <SimpleLineIcon onClick={() => setToggleIcon(!toggleIcon)} /> : <AntDesign <SimpleLineIcon onClick={() => setToggleIcon(!toggleIcon)} />}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: This does not work, there is no way to refresh essentially so it never notices that I pressed it.

Comment: Setting state will automatically trigger a re-render of the component.

Comment: You are a Legend.